# Create files using grep and wildcards with input file

Tags: shell, redirect, grep, cygwin, wildcard

This should be a no-brainer, but apparently I have no brain today.

I have 50 20-gig logs that contain entries from multiple apps, one of which addes a transaction ID to its log lines.  I have 42 transaction IDs I need to review, and I'd like to parse out the appropriate lines into separate files.

To do a single file, the command would be simply,

```
grep CDBBDEADBEEF2020X02393 server.log* > CDBBDEADBEEF2020X02393.log
```

that creates a log isolated to that transaction, from all 50 server.logs.

Now, I have a file with 42 txnIDs (shortening to 4 here):

```
CDBBDEADBEEF2020X02393 
CDBBDEADBEEF6548X02302 
CDBBDE15644F2020X02354 
ABBDEADBEEF21014777811
```

And I wrote:

```
#/bin/sh
grep $1 server.\* > $1.log
```

But that is not working.  Changing the shebang to #/bin/bash -xv, gives me this weird output (obviously I'm playing with what the correct escape magic must be):

```
$ ./xtrakt.sh B7F6E465E006B1F1A
#!/bin/bash -xv
grep - ./server\.\*
' grep - './server.*
: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried the command line

```
grep - server.* < txids.txt > $1
```

But OBVIOUSLY that $1 is pointless and I have no idea how to get a file named per txid using the input redirect form of the command.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.  I haven't gone the route of doing a foreach in the shell script, because I want grep to put the original filename in the output lines so I can examine context later if I need to.

Also - it would be great to have the server.* files ordered numerically (server.log.1, server.log.2 NOT server.log.1, server.log.10...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
while read -r txid
do
    grep "$txid" server.* > "$txid.log"
done < txids.txt
```

and for the file ordering - rename files with one digit to two digit, with leading zeroes, e.g. `mv server.log.1 server.log.01`.